# int cannot be converted to charsequence

Tags: java, arraylist, int, charsequence

I am trying to loop through my arraylist and print email addresses that are invalid.  To be invalid, the address does not contain an @ sign or a period.

I am getting an error, int cannot be converted to charsequence for my method.

```
public static void print_invalid_emails(){
    for (int i = 0; i < studentList.size(); i++) {
        if (studentList.get(i).getEmail().contains('@' + '.')){
            System.out.println("Scanning Roster");
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Invalid email address, " + studentList.get(i).getEmail());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens when you run this code?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that Java treats `'@' + '.'` as an addition of two characters, not as a concatenation of a string. The result of this addition is UNICODE code point of `@` plus unicode code point of `.`, expressed as an `int`.

If you want to check that the item is missing a `.` or a `@`, you should perform these two checks in two separate calls of `contains(...)`

Answer (score 1):

The bug is here:

```
if (studentList.get(i).getEmail().contains('@' + '.')){
```

It should be:

```
if (studentList.get(i).getEmail().contains("@") || studentList.get(i).getEmail().contains(".")){
```